# SymetricDS Multi-NodeGroup Replication

Tags: symmetricds

In SymmetricDS we've been replicating successfully from master to children and children to master for years. We're now needing to replicate from master to master (mirror) where the latter master is a mirrored reporting database. Keep in mind that some tables between the master/child relationship are asynchronous. When we build out the SymmetricDS configurations for the master we see a successful initial load. We also see successful replication between master --> mirror. What we cannot resolve is the replication between child --> master --> mirror. Any changes occurring on a child, as usual, replicates to the master, but nothing moves to the mirror. If a change happens directly on the master, the mirror is updated. We need both.

Comment: symmetric-server-3.7.2, mySQL 5.7.21

Comment: For some reason, the sym_node table in SymmetricDS includes a node_group_id column. Since the sym_node column is unique, this then requires that a node can only be assigned to one node group. At face value, this seems to be very limiting as one node should be able to be included in multiple node groups (master-children / master-mirrors), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Configure sync on incoming batch as explained in the chapter on bi-directional synchronization https://www.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_bi_directional_synchronization

Comment: I don't believe bi-directional is the answer. If master receives data from child_1 it needs to replicate to its master mirror (one way), not back to child_1. I don't want child_1 to receive it's own data and I don't want child_2,3,4, etc. to receive child_1 data. This works perfectly as is, except the master mirror doesn't receive child_x data.

Comment: bi-directional synchronization excludes the source of data to forward to. with the right routing data from all children will be synced only to the mirror. need help to create such a routing expression?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a work-around. In sym_data the node_id is recorded to prevent looping. This value represents a child node. The mirror master has no contact or relationship with a child node, so when the master trigger fires, it records the child node and so the master mirror ignores it. If I modify the triggers to hard code the master node in the result instead of the child node the master mirror then processes the result. Again, I believe there is a limitation in SymmetricDS with regards to the sym_node table as it should not require a node_group_id (a node should be allowed to join many node_groups).